# What is UpVotes of users in database schema documentation?

Tags: support, voting, data-dump

A typical child of the `users.xml` looks as follows:

```
<row Id="2"
     Reputation="101"
     CreationDate="2010-07-19T14:01:36.697"
     DisplayName="Geoff Dalgas"
     LastAccessDate="2013-11-12T22:07:23.783"
     WebsiteUrl="http://stackoverflow.com"
     Location="Corvallis, OR"
     AboutMe="Wondering why the HTML in here isn't escaped, frankly." 
     Views="25" UpVotes="3" DownVotes="0" Age="37" AccountId="2"/>
```

My questions are

1) What is "UpVotes"? Is it the number of upvotes the user **contributes** or the number of upvotes he/she **receives**?

2) How do I find out the number of upvotes a post receives? I checked `posts.xml` and the answer is definitely not there.

Comment: 1) It's the number of upvotes that the user contributes. 
2) I think it should be in PostFeedback , VoteTypeId=3 , well at least that's how it is in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Users.xml the row holds in `UpVotes` the number of up votes on posts that the user contributes (as indicated by @dronehinge).

You'll find up- and downvotes in the Votes.xml.

A typical row looks like this:

```
 <row Id="4422" 
      PostId="858" 
      VoteTypeId="2" 
      CreationDate="2013-11-04T00:00:00.000" />
```

You are interested in

- VoteTypeId="2"  for up votes
- VoteTypeId="3"  for down votes

for a specific PostId

The datadump is a subset of the data available in SEDE but the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) has extra information on the entities and attributes that do match.

Comment: Great to know that UpMod=UpVote; DownMod=DownVote! Thank you very much!

Comment: What kinds of votes does it consider? Question / answer / comments / others?

Comment: Only votes on posts but it also includes accept, favorite. For the complete list see the doc. @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩

Comment: @rene where are the docs? I can only find http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 that is the documentation we have

Comment: I couldn't find it explained there, and linked to here. Thanks.