# Do the upvotes/downvotes shown on the profile page and in SEDE include votes on the deleted posts?

Tags: support, down-votes, data-explorer, up-votes

Information about number of up/downvotes cast by a specific users is displayed both in the user's profile and is also available in SEDE. In the user profile, it is in the part "votes cast" in the activity tab. In SEDE, the table users has columns [downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1367197/users-who-cast-most-downvotes) and [upvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1367198/users-who-cast-most-upvotes). See also: [What is UpVotes of users in database schema documentation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260897)

Do these numbers include votes on the posts which have already been deleted? Or is it number of votes only on the posts which still exist?

Comment: `the part "votes cast" in the activity tab` --> [Yes, this includes votes on deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351184/8967612).

Comment: I tried to confirm if the numbers on SEDE also include votes on deleted posts and I found something strange. My "votes cast" on Stack Overflow are 2555. The count that returned by SEDE is `1061 + 1489 = 2550`. I'm not sure why it's different (yet very close). Note that that's also _not_ the number that excludes deleted posts (that one can be checked in the "Votes" tab of one's user profile). **Edit:** I found the same discrepancy on Meta.SE as well (198 vs 179). What gives?!

Comment: @41686d6564 If the difference is small enough, the explanation is most likely that it is caused by the votes cast since the last update of SEDE. (The data are updated once a week, now you can see there: "Data updated Jan 24 at 10:05".) I'd say that information in your comments answers my question, so perhaps you'd be willing to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351184/8967612) on Meta Stack Overflow by [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson), the value of “votes cast” in the user profile includes votes on deleted posts. You can also easily confirm that by checking the “Votes” tab in your profile and comparing the “votes cast” number with the number of upvotes and downvotes displayed there (the “Votes” tab does *not* include votes on deleted posts).

To quote animuson:

> The number in the grey box is the total number of all votes you've ever cast. The number in your votes tab is just a count of how many are being displayed back to you. We don't display votes on deleted posts to users in that list, so they're not included in that count.

Now that we know that, we can compare the “Votes cast” number to the number returned by SEDE to confirm that it also includes votes on deleted posts. You might, however, see a small difference due to how frequently SEDE is updated as discussed in the comments.